# Issues upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1.2 ad Spring Data Solr 4.3.15

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-solr, spring-data-commons

I was using Spring Boot 2.x and with Spring Data SOLR 4.3.12 and Spring Data Commons 2.7.14, my app works normally connecting and querying SOLR.

**I upgraded Spring Boot to 3.1.2 and spring Data SOLR 4.3.15 and Spring Data Commons 2.7.14**, they are no longer compatible, as I see the below compilation error it is not available in my classpath.

> java: cannot access
> org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository class file for
> org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository not found

**If I upgrade Spring Data Commons 3.1.2, my build is successful**. But starting the app throws the below error.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/data/convert/EntityInstantiators  at
> org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.(MappingSolrConverter.java:128)
> at
> org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.getDefaultSolrConverter(SolrTemplate.java:669)
> at
> org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.afterPropertiesSet(SolrTemplate.java:726)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
> ... 15 common frames omitted

Can someone help how I can resolve this? If Spring Data Commons is not upgraded to be compatible with Spring Boot 3.1.2, Is there a way I can still use the old version (2.7.14) of Spring Data Commons for Spring Data SOLR (4.3.15) in Maven and my other dependencies that rely on Spring Data Commons (3.1.2) can continue to use the latest version excluding the old version.

Comment: No there isn't. The Spring Data SOLR project has been abandoned quite some time ago (https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-solr). So either don't upgrade to Spring Boot 3.x and keep using SOLR (for as long as it works) or switch to something like Spring Data Elasticsearch instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but today I found this library: https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spring-data-solr

Looks like it is port of spring-data-solar to Spring Data 3.1.0 Want to try it on my local project after update to Spring Boot 3.x. Also it is available on Maven Central repository, so you can try it to and provide your feedback.